# Big white "box" when number of comments flags exceeded

Tags: bug, comment-flags

Apparently, another change has been made to comment flagging.

Previously, when I flagged too quickly (under 5 seconds) I got a red message, which was annoying and I'm glad it's gone.

Today, flagging comments in a meta discussion, when I went too quickly there was a big white box that then went away and the comments dialog reappeared. That was OK, although a bit disconcerting with no message being visible.

But then I exceeded the number of allowed comments without realizing it - I'm used to having a much larger number on SO. That big white box appeared again and wouldn't go away. I had to manually refresh my browser (IE 11 running on Win7).

(I've tried to include a picture of the screen, but I'm getting an error when trying to upload the .png.)